# How to access parameters passed from JSP as hidden input to HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I am having a jsp page which is opening an html page and passing few hidden parameters. like below...

```
<form name="DMSForm" method="post" action="<bean:write name="URL"/>" >
<input type="hidden" name="userName" value="<bean:write name="userName"/>">
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="<bean:write name="password"/>">
```

HTML page is having lot of other code, beside that it is calling an url for which it needs to send these userName and password received from JSP. like below...

```
<frame longdesc="/styles/blank.htm" name="topFrame" id="topFrame" src="**/servlets/servlets.CH_Vault?INT=1&amp;Name=UserNameFromJSP;&amp;Password=passwordFromJSP;**" border="0" frameborder="no" noresize scrolling="no"/>
```

How can I access userName and password passed by JSP in html?

Comment: Can u show some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, HTML nor JavaScript has nothing to handle a given URL parameters.

You can do that with a little bit of JavaScript

```
function gup( name, url ) {
  // If you don't specify an URL in the parameters, it will take the current URL of the browser
  if (!url) url = location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( url );
  return results == null ? null : results[1];
}

var testUrl = "www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&promo=m2-m3-m4-m5"
var promo_param = gup('promo', 'test') // returns "m2-m3-m4-m5"
```